# How would you argue against the bold statement that stationary is needed for sensible predictions

Tags: forecasting, stationarity

We talked about a (time series) process generating observations. Somebody gave the bold statement: "Regression or predictions for general processes only make sense (generalize well) when the process is stationary".

What methods are there to predict/regress on non-stationary processes? I was thinking about other co-integration, but maybe you have more better arguments.

Comment: "...only..." is the extreme part of the statement.  There are plenty of models of non-stationary processes that permit prediction.  Many of them ultimately involve stationary processes, such as models where a finite difference becomes stationary or time series that are nonlinear functions of stationary processes.  Consequently, the number of possible methods you ask about is unlimited.

Comment: You may want to point the statementer to their friendly local weather forecaster, who seem to be able to forecast hourly weather rather well, although it is quite non-stationary, with pronounced daily seasonality.